# assigning to an associative array slice in php

Tags: php, associative-array, slice

In perl, I could assign a list to multiple values in a hash, like so:

```
# define the hash...
my %hash = (
  foo => 1,
  bar => 2,
  baz => 3,
);

# change foo, bar, and baz to 4, 5, and 6 respectively
@hash{ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' } = ( 4, 5, 6 );
```

Is there any way to do the same in php? In fact, is there even a way to get a slice of an assoc array at all?

Comment: Note: I already know about list and the point of the question was to find a more elegant solution than the following:
    list ( $array['a'], $array['b'], $array['c'], $array['d'], $array['e'], $array['f'], $array['g'], $array['h'], $array['i'], $array['j'], $array['k'], $array['l'], $array['m'] ) = some_function();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent to the Perl syntax.  But you can make an array of the keys of interest and use that to change only part of your array.

```
$koi=array('foo', 'bar', 'baz' );
foreach($koi as $k){
  $myarr[$k]++; //or whatever
}
```

or

```
array_walk($myarr, create_function('&$v,$k','$v=(in_array($k,$koi))? $v*2 : $v;')); //you'd have to define $koi inside the function
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple one-liner (some of these methods require newer versions of PHP than were available at the time of asking):

```
$hash = array(
    'foo'=>1,
    'bar'=>2,
    'baz'=>3,
);

$hash = array_merge( $hash, array( 'foo' => 4, 'bar' => 4, 'baz' => 5 ) );
```

PHP Manual entry for [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

If you're looking to GET a set of specific array keys, you can use this:

```
$subset = array_intersect_key( $hash, array_fill_keys( array( 'foo', 'baz' ), '' ) );
```

PHP Manual entries for [array_intersect_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and
[array_fill_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php).

Answer (score 1):

Define the hash:

```
$hash = array(
  'foo' => 1,
  'bar' => 2,
  'baz' => 3,
);

# change foo, bar, and baz to 4, 5, and 6 respectively
list($hash['foo'], $hash['bar'], $hash['baz']) = array( 4, 5, 6 );

# or change one by one
$hash['foo'] = 1;
$hash['bar'] = 2;
$hash['baz'] = 3;
```

See the list() function in manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Comment: list() is really in the opposite direction: it takes a list of variables and an array and assigns each item in the array to the corresponding variable (i.e. it's a way to get things OUT of an array rather than a way to put things IN).

Comment: You could do something like $info = array(4,5,6); list($a['foo'], $a['bar'], $a['baz']) = $info; but using "list" there really isn't buying you anything.

Comment: this method works, but it's exactly what i was trying to avoid. I don't want to type the name of the assoc array for every single key. something like "assoc_array_slice( $array, 'foo','bar','baz') = array( 4, 5, 6 )" is what I'm really looking for.

Comment: Yes, but there is no 1-to-1 equivalent to the given example in PHP, I try to the closest.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. However, you could use a function like this:

```
function assignSlice($ar,$keys,$args) {
  if (count($keys) !== count($args)) {
    // may want to handle more gracefully;
    // simply returns original if numbers of keys and values
    // don't match
    return $ar;
  }                                                 
  foreach ($keys as $index=>$key) {
    $ar[$key] = $args[$index];
  }
  return $ar;
}

$test = array(
    'foo'=>1,
    'bar'=>2,
    'baz'=>3,
    );

$newtest = assignSlice($test,array('foo','bar'),array(4,5));
```

Edit: adjusted code in response OP's comment on question.